# Arduino Uno Reading Fuses

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, isp, oscillator-clock

I am trying to read the fuse values for the Arduino Uno, but keep getting the following results returned back to me:

```
enter code hereavrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Dec 16 2013 at 17:26:24
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/etc/avrdude.conf"
     User configuration file is "/Users/hd334/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

     Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem1421
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
     AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
     Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
     PAGEL                         : PD7
     BS2                           : PC2
     RESET disposition             : dedicated
     RETRY pulse                   : SCK
     serial program mode           : yes
     parallel program mode         : yes
     Timeout                       : 200
     StabDelay                     : 100
     CmdexeDelay                   : 25
     SyncLoops                     : 32
     ByteDelay                     : 0
     PollIndex                     : 3
     PollValue                     : 0x53
     Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                       Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
       flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : Arduino
     Description     : Arduino
     Hardware Version: 3
     Firmware Version: 4.4
     Vtarget         : 0.3 V
     Varef           : 0.3 V
     Oscillator      : 28.800 kHz
     SCK period      : 3.3 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 0

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:00, E:00, L:00)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I have tried using avrisp as the programmer too, but this reports an invalid device signature. If I override the device signature check with -F I get the same results as above.

I am using an Uno as the ISP to another uno and have connected the two together as detailed in 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

I have boot loaded the Arduino Atmega328P boot loader and from the fuse settings given in the boards.txt file expect to see:
lfuse reads 0xff
hfuse reads 0xde
efuse reads 0x05

Another question is with the low fuse set to 0xff the CKDIV8 is programmed so won't the clock be set to 2MHz?

Please help

Comment: CKDIV should be `0` to enable the divide by 8. Since it's set to `1` the clock frequency will be 16MHz (when using a 16MHz crystal, that is).

Comment: Did you do step 5 (`Note for the Arduino Uno: you'll need to add a 10 uF capacitor between reset and ground.`)?

Comment: I connected a 10uF cap between rst on the board to be programmed and the GND on the ISP board

Comment: RE CLKDIV8 thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your questions about clock division settings: have a look at [this pretty tool](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/), it gives you a avrdude query for setting fuses (take care!). The CKDIV8 bit of the low fuse is set by default, so an AT328p will run at 1MHz, clearing this bit will result in 8 MHz.

When flashing you should never override any checks as this may damage/lock your chip.

I see that avrdudes states the supply voltage to be 0.3 volts which is far to low for communication. Any received bits would be low level and therefore any information read will be 0. ISPs usually provide a supply voltage which often can be selected by switches on the programmer. If you are sure your programmer is allright, check your circuit in general.

Btw, which ISP-model do you use?
Is your mcu assembled on a custom pcb (setup?)? If yes, do you have an arduino(like) board to verify this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a stk500 (USB <> ISP programmer) to read atmega328p fuses. I use this cmd:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avrdude.exe -CC:"\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -patmega328p -cstk500 -PCOM9 -e -Ulfuse:r:-:i -Uhfuse:r:-:i -Uefuse:r:-:i
```

Sometime ago I had some issues with device signatures because I missed the "p" in atmega328p definition.

As a tip, you can check the Arduino verbose to help you with more information:

FILE >> PREFERENCES

SHOW VERBOSE OUTPUT DURING: [x] COMPILATION [x] UPLOAD